# Probability of strings haveing ones in the same position

Tags: probability

Can any probability master help me calculating these probabilities?

I have 114 strings of length 15000 that can have maximum 80 ones.
Taken two positions, what is the probability of having two strings with a one in that position? What about three strings?

The same problem with different numbers

I have 49 strings of length 10000 that can have maximum 1093 ones.
Taken two positions, what is the probability of having two strings with a one in that position? What about three strings?

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: What does this value mean: `80 onse`

Comment: Misspelled, 80 ones, 1s. Strings like 10101010110101010000010011

Comment: When you say "the probability of having two strings", do you mean exactly two strings, or at least two strings?

Comment: I am insterested in two, three or more

Comment: the possibility that one string has a one on any given position is `80/15000` in the first example

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about calculating probabilities. This site is for programming questions.

Comment: @Mat calculating chance is a part of programming in a way. I find it an in between question. It could benefit other programmers.

Comment: @Mouser: eating and drinking is part of programming too, in a way. If OP is looking for an algorithm to compute these probabilities, fine - just reword the question that way. If the OP's just after the result, this is a plain math question and doesn't belong here.

Comment: Btw the answer is (drawing from high school math memory): `(80/15000)n * 100` where `n` is the number of strings as exponent. Generic `(a/b)n * 100` where a is the number of ones and b is the total amount of characters. Couldn't as a teacher resist to solve this problem :-) (not a math teacher).

Comment: I can withdar the question if necessary, these a binary strings for an encryption task.

Answer (score 0):

This is the formula:

```
(a/b)n * 100  //where a is the number of ones and b is the total amount of characters and n the exponentiation.
```

Pseudo code:

```
float probability = pow( (str.match(1).length / str.length), strAmount ) * 100;
```

Answer in percentages.